# How to combine multiple rows into one line

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very simple query:

```
select date,route,employee
from information
where date=Trunc(Sysdate)
```

however, since for some routes, there are more than 2 employees are assigned, so the query will return two rows

[image]

But I want get one route for one row, so the ideal output should be:

[image]

so the two names are in the same row, and combine with "|", so how can I achieve this goal in PL/SQL?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you running?  There are different answers based on your release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use listagg function, but you have to add Date and Route to grouping functions as well

```
SELECT LISTAGG(emp, ' | ')
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY emp) "Emp",
       MAX(date) "Date",
       MAX(route) "Route"
FROM information
WHERE date=Trunc(Sysdate);
```